# Ensure minimum number of rows in a resultset

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm working with Java and MSSQL, I'm running a query with a where statement and wanted to retrieve always at least 20 elements, sometimes the query retrieve 20 records with data but sometimes without data, I'm using top 20, but when is there no match with the passed criteria the resultset comes empty.

I need a way to ensure at least 20 elements always in the resultset does not matter if I have 20 rows with null elements. If query return 10 elements I need 10 rows more inserted in the resulset.

I'm looking to do that using only SQL statement. I have this but does not fit what I need

```
SELECT top 20 null as PROFILETITLE, null as DOCID 
union all
SELECT t.pag_id,t.contract_number
from (select 1 as adummy) a
left join (
    select pag_id, contract_number from pag_log where pag_id  = 11
) t on 1=1
```

Not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: Use a tally table as the basis for your query. You just need to add ROW_NUMBER to your query so you can join it to the tally table.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I need to build an excel file and using reference I need to have the first 20 rows pointing to one template table and the following 20 rows pointing to the second template table, so I need always 40 records to make this work

Comment: So why not fill the rows you have, and programmatically add the empty rows without the overhead of database access for empty rows?

Comment: It is because this is a generic endpoint so no logic need to be added, I know that I can do that with java but want to have the resultset ready to be printed in the excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 20  *
FROM (
    SELECT Col1, Col2
    FROM YourDesiredData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 20 NULL, NULL 
    FROM sys.all_columns
) TMP
```

Comment: That works perfectly man, the point that I did not was SELECT TOP 20 NULL, NULL FROM sys.all_columns =)

Comment: Personally, I don't like the unnecessary hit to sys.all_columns. That is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a dummy table with just the numbers 1 through 20 in it, and then left join to that.

In my example, I'll use a CTE to fill my table.

```
with justATable(rowNumber)
as
(
  select 1
  union all
  select rowNumber + 1
  from justATable where rowNumber < 20
)

select realData.pag_id, realData.contract_number
from justATable
left outer join 
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by contract_number) as RowNumber,
       pag_id, 
       contract_number 
from pag_log 
where pag_id  = 11) realData
on justATable.rowNumber = realData.RowNumber
```

Comment: I believe this is the tally table strategy, but this seems to be code for stored procedure not just plain sql or I'm wrong ?

Comment: That's just plain SQL. You can declare a CTE, and then use it in the next SQL statement.